# Forecasting Incoming Payments - Increasing Variance in a Forecast

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, variance, forecasting, excel

I am forecasting daily incoming deposits for a bank for the next 3-6 months. This is going to be used to forecast the bank's liquidity going forward. I have used both Holt-Winters and a time series regression model using 9 variables. The time series works the best, but the low RMSE and strong fit miss quite a bit of variance when compared to the real data. Because we need to predict liquidity, its important to accurately forecast swings in liquidity so that the bank knows what is available.

What is the best way to replicate the variance so that the bank has a better understanding of how much liquidity it will have?

I am working in excel so my solution is to have a prediction fit and then add more randomness by adding an error variable to each forecast using the NORMINV(RAND() with a mean of zero and a SD of the distribution of the time series. Is this the best method? Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks,

Tame

[image: Chart of the variance discrepancy]

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like Quantile Regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression). I think you are probably more concerned about when your response variable is very large, so quantile regression could help you model a specific quantile (like the 95% quantile).

Comment: thanks! i will look into this.